# Updating Avatar column in Mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update avatar in my database with this statement.. I don't know what wrong but it is not going any help will be appreciated thanks.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $adminID = $_SESSION['adminID'];

    $type = explode('.', $_FILES['avatar']['name']);
    $type = $type[count($type)-1];      
    $url = 'assests/images/users/'.uniqid(rand()).'.'.$type;
    if(in_array($type, array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'JPG', 'GIF', 'JPEG', 'PNG'))) {
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'])) {           
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $url)) {

                try {                                           
                        //insert into database with a prepared statement
                        $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE admin SET avatar = '$url' WHERE adminID =  $adminID");
                        $stmt->execute(array(

                        ));
                //else catch the exception and show the error.
                    } catch(PDOException $e) {
                        $error[] = $e->getMessage();
                        }                       
            }       
        } 
    }   
}
```

Comment: What's wrong? what is the result you are expecting and what do you get?

Comment: I am expecting it to insert the $url into the database

Comment: yes but what happens instead? any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching and reading I have been able to get it to work thanks all.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $adminID = $_SESSION['adminID'];

    $type = explode('.', $_FILES['avatar']['name']);
    $type = $type[count($type)-1];      
    $url = 'assets/images/users/'.$_SESSION['username'].'.'.$type;
    if(in_array($type, array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'JPG', 'GIF', 'JPEG', 'PNG'))) {
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'])) {           
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $url)) {

                try {   //insert into database with a prepared statement
                        $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE admin SET avatar = '$url' WHERE adminID =  $adminID");
                        $stmt->execute(array(
                            $adminID
                        ));

                        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL='.$location.'">';
                        exit;
                    } 
                //else catch the exception and show the error.
                catch(PDOException $e) {
                        $error[] = $e->getMessage();
                    }                       
            }       
        } 
    }   
}
```